# Copy value from child case to Parent case,there was an error

Tags: pega

Actually i want to copy values from child case to Parent Case, i have add smart shape called "Update Case",But there was an error during the sub case process,

"com.pega.pegarules.pub.generator.UnresolvedAssemblyError: Failed to find instance CTC-FW-CeylonTrFW-Work-VehiclePolicy.UpdateParentCase",

parent case is : CTC-FW-CeylonTrFW-Work-VehiclePolicy

Child Case is : CTC-FW-CeylonTrFW-Work-AssessVehicle

Here Attached with screen shoots

Could you please help me to solve this issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fauW0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear.
Your `UpdateParentCase` should be present in parent class `CTC-FW-CeylonTrFW-Work-VehiclePolicy`.

Comment: Thank you very much